# Clone columns, but formulas need to be shifted too - with VBA

Tags: vba, excel

I have a cell (A1) which conatins a number, ie. A1 = 4. This means, that I have to clone 4 times a column from a sheet.

It would be very easy, but the trick is, that the cloned columns cells may contain formulas too, which should be shifted by the number of the clone. For the better understanding here is an example:

If the columns contains =A1, the first clone should contain =B1, the second one =C1 and so on.

The copy script, without shifting:

```
Private Sub Worksheet_Change(ByVal Target As Range)
If Target.Address = "$A$1" Then 
    For i = 0 To Target
        ActiveWorkbook.Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(3).Copy Destination:=Sheets("Sheet1").Columns(i) 'Columns(3) is the column that I am cloning
    Next i
End If
```

End Sub

How should I solve this problem?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you have a formula (=A1 for example) then the column is automatically shifted, if you want a different behaviour, use $ in front of the column or row:

If you write =$A1, then the column will always stay the same but the row can change
If you write =A$1, the column will change but the row will stay the same
If you write = $A$1 both the column and row will stay the same

Here's my example: In A1 i use the formula =A2. I entered 5 into A2 so A1 shows 5 as well. Now i ran this code:

```
Dim i As Integer

For i = 1 To 4 Step 1

    Cells(1, 1).EntireColumn.Copy Destination:=Cells(1, i).EntireColumn
Next i
```

Now B1 has the formula =B2, C1 has =C2 and D1 has =D2

If you wouldn't want the formula to change, enter =$A$2 into A1

Hope this helps somehow

Comment: Thank you so much! I don't know why didn't think about that, my bad!